# If I'm playing a game where one of my characters died and then that character is revived how would that be handled/what do I do?

Tags: player-characters

So I was playing dnd and I was on my second character it was heading toward the end of the game and then an my first characters wife got a wish and wished my first character back to life and that was where we left off now I don't know what I should do or how this will work. does anyone have some advice?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! What edition of D&D were you playing? Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already, and check out the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) for more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: This does feel like an opinion based vtc. However... I feel this can be answered in ways that we answer gm-techniques questions.

Comment: I think we could remove the opinion part simply be removing "what should I do" and leaving "how this will work" as there are only a few constrained ways that this could work in practice, and general advice is likely to point to just one or two options used in most games in practice.

Comment: @NeilSlater Yeah, the question basically boils down to "what are my options?" and there's really only 2 or 3 reasonable options.

Comment: @RyanThompson THe problem is that while there may be only 2-3 reasonable options (are there?), there are many many unreasonable. And all are equally valid without constraints on what makes one option better than another.

Comment: @BenBarden Please don't answer in comments.

Comment: @NautArch It's not trying to be an answer.  It's trying to be a "this is not the place to go for the answer to this question".

Comment: Maybe these sources here could also help with guidance/advice for you and be useful to have a look at! https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go